# Error array used as initializer and i don't know the error

Tags: c++

The failed is in the constructor of the class manejo.cpp, the error is "manejo.cpp:3:16: error: array used as initializer" and i don't know where this error.

to down is attached the source code of the class manejo.hpp and the implementation of manejo.cpp, thanks

```
#include "manejo.hpp"

manejo::manejo(){}
manejo::~manejo(){}
```

Hpp

```
#ifndef __MANEJO_HPP
#define _MANEJO_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

class manejo{

private:

     char cadena[128]="";
     vector <string> linea;
     long cantidadPD = 0;
     vector <string> palabras;
     int Creglas = 0;
     vector <string> reglas;
     long atoi(const char *str);


public:

     manejo();
     ~manejo();
     void EstablecerVariables();
     int StoInt (string numero);

};

#endif
```

Comment: `char cadena[128]="";` you can't do this. Did you actually try to google the error you're getting?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11? If not, you cannot initialize non-static data members at the point of declaration (as you do with `cadena`). As an aside, check your include guards, and don't use double underscores. These are reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
 char cadena[128]="";
```

is not legal in traditional C++ (it is legal in C++11 but clearly you're not using that because otherwise you wouldn't get this error). Delete `=""`, initialise data members in your constructor, not in your class. E.g.

```
manejo::manejo()
{
    cadena[0] = '\0';
    ...
}
```

Comment: In-class initialization **is** legal since C++11.

Comment: @BartoszKP: That doesn't matter. The answer should mention that it is valid since C++11.

Comment: Now, what does *"traditional C++"* mean?

Comment: @Nawaz Obviously it's the C++ I know

Comment: @Nawaz I don't know why it *should mention*. This topic clearly does not concern C++11. Sure, you're right that it's *good to mention* this, but it's certainly not obligatory.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Because in the current version it is allowed.

Comment: @BartoszKP it could be as simple as OP has looked at some current C++ example, and has either a non-conforming compiler, or a compiler that needs to be told to use C++11. The fact that they can't compile C++11 doesn't mean they don't want to use it.